# Bazel: share macro between multiple http_archive BUILD files

Tags: bazel

My project depends on some external libraries which I have to bazelfy myself. Thus, my `WORKSPACE`:

```py
http_archive(
    name = "external_lib_component1",
    build_file = "//third_party:external_lib_component1.BUILD",
    sha256 = "xxx",
    urls = ["https://example.org/external_lib_component1.tar.gz"],
)

http_archive(
    name = "external_lib_component2",
    build_file = "//third_party:external_lib_component2.BUILD",
    sha256 = "yyy",
    urls = ["https://example.org/external_lib_component2.tar.gz"],
)

...
```

The two entries above are similar, and `external_lib_component{1, 2}.BUILD` share a lot of code.
What is the best way to share code (macros) between them?

Just putting a `shared_macros.bzl` file into `third_party/` won't work, because it will not be copied into
the archive location on build (only the `build_file` is copied).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place a `bzl` file such a In your`./third_party/shared_macros.bzl` into your tree as you've mentioned.

Then in the `//third_party:external_lib_component1.BUILD` and `//third_party:external_lib_component2.BUILD` you provide for your external dependencies, you can load symbols from that shared file using:

```
load("@//third_party:shared_macros.bzl", ...)
```

Labels starting with `@//` refer to packages from the main repository, even when used in an external dependency (as they would otherwise be rooted when starting with `//`. You can for check docs on [labels](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#labels), in particular the last paragraph.

---

Alternatively you can also refer to the "parent" project by its name. If in your `WORKSPACE` file you've had:

```
workspace(name = "parent")
```

You could say:

```
load("@parent//third_party:shared_macros.bzl", ...)
```

---

Note: in versions prior to 2.0.0 you might want to add `--incompatible_remap_main_repo` if you mixed both of above approaches in your project.

Comment: thank you, I used the first solution (`load("@//third_party:shared_macros.bzl", ...)`) and it works!